# Different size of int type on different devices

Tags: ios, objective-c

Consider the following code fragment:

```
if (((int)[@"foo" rangeOfString @"a"].location+1) > 0)
{
    // found a
}
else
{
  // not found a
}
```

On release builds, it works fine (i.e. goes to //not found a) on newer devices such as iPad Air. But on old devices such as iPad 2, it does not (I.e. goes to // found a).

When debugging via Xcode it works fine on all devices.

PS: I know the above is poor coding practice and I should be using the following. But I am trying to understand the above behavior.

```
if ([@"foo" rangeOfString @"a"].location != NSNotFound)
{
   // found a
}
else
{
    // not found a
}
```

Comment: Can you print `(int)[@"foo" rangeOfString @"a"].location+1` to see what happened?

Comment: On newer devices where it works, it returns -2147483648. On other devices 2147483648.

Answer (score 1):

`rangeOfString.location` returns `NSNotFound` if the string does not contain the substring.

`NSNotFound` is declared as `NSIntegerMax` which is 32 bit on 32 bit systems and  64 bit on 64 bit systems.

The problem occurs by casting the type to `int` which is always 32 bit.

Casting a 64 bit integer to `int` will loose either precision and/or the sign.

Comment: Thanks. But do you know why it is treated as 64-bit on older devices only and also how it works fine while debugging on the same device?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may have to do with 32 bit and 64 bit architecture, and perhaps the optimizer is messing with it

print the values you are getting out of it

Answer (score 0):

NSInteger is either 32 or 64 bit. int is 32 bit. That should explain everything.